# actionscript error 1119

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to actionscript and have to create a DDR-like game for an assignment. I converted all my arrows into symbols and gave them an instance name.

so far I didn't include any functions; just set all my symbols to visible = false or true. But for whatever reason it just plays everything anyway.

And I'm getting an error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property visible through a reference with static type fl.motion:AnimatorFactory.

Answer (score 1):

In Flash, if there is a code error, it basically ignores all actionscript and auto-loops every MovieClip in the project that exists on the stage (the default behaviour for MovieClips)

The 1119 error means just what is says, you're trying to set a property (visible) on an object of a type the does not have that property (AnimatorFactory)

You'll need to post a code example to get more specific help if you still need it.

Answer (score 1):

thanks!
there's literally no function coding as of yet. I was just starting with setting the properties and seeing if that works...

package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

```
public class GameAS3 extends MovieClip{

public function GameAS3(){
    //visibility
    //background layer
        logo_mc.visible = true;
        lounge_mc.visible = true;
        line_mc.visible = true;
    //Welcome layer
        welcome_mc.visible = true;
    //Final Arrow layer: the arrows to hit at the top
        ArrowLeft_mc.visible = true;
        ArrowDown_mc.visible = true;
        ArrowUp_mc.visible = true;
        ArrowRight_mc.visible = true;
    //glow layer: glowing symbols that will activate every time you hit one
        glowLeft_mc.visible = false;
        glowDown_mc.visible = false;
        glowUp_mc.visible = false;
        glowRight_mc.visible = false;
    //the arrows that go to the beat 
        left_mc.visible = false;
        down_mc.visible = false;
        up_mc.visible = false;
        right_mc.visible = false;
    //menu invisible: after welcome you press next to see the menu
        easy_btn.visible = false;
        medium_btn.visible = false;
        hard_btn.visible = false;
        expert_btn.visible = false;
        career_btn.visible = false;
    //score: will pop according to how you hit it
        miss_mc.visible = false;
        okay_mc.visible = false;
        perfecto_mc.visible = false;
}
```

}